# Where do I set init params for WP TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

Apologies if this is a stupid question but I have researched it and have drawn a blank.

I want to stop the `WordPress Advanced TinyMCE` plugin inserting  tags all over and I know that the answer is to add this

```
tinyMCE.init({
        invalid_elements : "span"
});
```

to the init file. My problem is that /public_html/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js appears to be minified and I have no idea where to add my few lines of code.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: what other files do you see in this directory? tiny_mce.js is not the configuration file

Answer (score 1):

Try the filter tiny_mce_before_init check it out in the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init)
Also check out [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ran out of time and bought a gig on Fiverr, where the answer was to add the snippet above, wrapped in  tags, to the header.php file, just before the  tag.

This worked initially, but then TinyMCE insisted on inserting  tags again.

I finally lost patience and added this to the custom css file ...

span { display: block; }

which worked, but only because I was trying to establish a top and bottom margin on a pee (sorry - gets deleted otherwise) tag originally.

WordPress is so smart in other ways, it remains a mystery why we have to put up with such a c**p editor.

Thanks for everyone's help.